# how do i move the bottom section to sit at the right side of the other headers and paragraphs

Tags: html, css, css-float

i'm trying to move the Uni section so that it sits at the side of the other paragraphs and headers. i've tried float left and it just doesn't seem to move.
http://jsfiddle.net/loopy333/0sz6kt0a/2/

any help would be great

```
<div  class ="container">
<div id="education" class ="learn-more">
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <h3>2003 - 2008 Haslingden High school</h3>

<p>9 GCSEs 
    Grades B - C</p>

<h3>2008 - 2010 Haslingden High School sixth form </h3>
<p>3 A levels   IT  (B)</p>
<p>Level 3 BTEC National Award in Applied science (Forensic science (Pass)</p>
<p>level 3 BTEC National Award in Media production (print-based media)  (Distinction)</p>

<div class="uni">
<h3>2010 - 2013     Bachelor of Science in Engineering and Multimedia Computing 2:2
        Manchester Metropolitan University</h3>

<p>BSE Course subjects Studied
Introduction to Programming, Object Oriented Programming 1,2 ,3 & 4, Algorithms, Structured Analysis and Design, Object Oriented Analysis and Design
Computer Architecture, Operating Systems
Network Fundamentals, Routing Concepts and Protocols, Local Area Networks (LAN) Switching and Wireless, Wide Area Networks (WAN) Services and Security
Database Concepts, Introduction to Database Programming
Visual Communications, Web Design, Digital Imaging, Web Design for Multiple Platforms, Human Computer Interaction.
Multimedia Design & Development, Computer Graphics, Animation in 2D& 3D, Digital Audio, Digital Video Production
Interactive Web Media.
</p>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.learn-more {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;

clear: both; 
overflow:auto;
}

.learn-more .uni {
float:left;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto; }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Put everything before it in another div container and float that container right. Remove the float from ```.uni```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are floating .uni but it is after .learn-more so it would only float elements that come after .uni

Also .uni will try and take up the entire width so you need to constrain the width so it makes room for the other section to float next to it.

```
.uni{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.learn-more{
    float:right;
}
```

This should make it work for you. Then depending on if you want it responsive or not you can change the width to a percentage. You could also acheive the same thing by having .uni first in your html and just float it left. Instead of floating .learn-more right.

See here for fiddle. (please not if you size the window to small .uni will pop down to the bottom again.

http://jsfiddle.net/uhwwrh3u/

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here:

1. Your **.uni** `div` is *inside* your **.learn-more** `div`, so it cannot move to the right of it.  You need to move it *outside* the **.learn-more** `div`, so it is a child of **container** instead.
2. Your width constraints don't allow a lot of room to the right of the **.learn-more** `div`.  I managed to make the **.uni** `div` fit by constraining the width to 150px, but you might want to re-jig things to make it look a little nicer. (Depending on the width of your browser window and your display, you might have to re-size things to make **.uni** `div` move to the right.)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sz6kt0a/3/)